# Excel: How does the =FILTERXML function work?

Tags: excel, xml

I'm trying to get FX rate from ECB in an Excel Spreadsheet. First of all I get the XML:

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D.USD.EUR.SP00.A?lastNObservations=1")
```

Then I try to get the exchange with the `FILTERXML` function:

```
=FILTERXML(cell_with_XML,"//message:genericdata/message:dataset/generic:series/generic:obs/generic:obsvalue/@value")
```

However, I always get a #VALUE error. Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check this [article.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747)

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with xml namespaces. Remove them with SUBSTITUTE, then write your XPath expression to get the data from the attribute, not the node.

Working example :

```
=FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(WEBSERVICE("https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D.USD.EUR.SP00.A?lastNObservations=1"),":",""),"//genericObsValue/@value")
```

Output :

[image: FX Rate]